# How to compile one directory above

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to compile a `scss` file to a directory above the each `scss`'s respective directory path.

So I have monitored a directory, lets say `root`

- root

  - dir 1

    - css `<-- Need the index.css here`
    - inner dir

      - index.scss
  - dir 2

    - inner dir

      - css `<-- Need the something.css here`
      - super inner dir

        - something.css

I'm using netbeans on Ubuntu and using the sass compiler (`/usr/bin/sass`) originally provided on the official website.

I've been tinkering with `input` and `output` values.

Have been able to make the `css` output in the same directory of the `scss` file but I need to output it to a directory relative to the `scss` file.

Comment: Where is your compile script? What are you using to compile? You have enough Stack rep to know you should provide way more information.

Comment: I was in a hurry, had to jump on a meeting, nonetheless.